# Как убрать заливку у элементов?

Tags: css

Как убрать данную заливку на телефонах, outline не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас кнопка сделала в виде ссылки, попробуйте `text-decoration:none` или `outline:none !important`

Comment: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

Comment: нашел вот это решение, помогло

Comment: @user281117, ответы - в ответы, а не в комментарии.